# VBA to extract values from a list until the sum is within a certain range

Tags: list, excel, vba

I have a list of values and I need to pull values from this list until the sum is somwhere between 1,200,000 and 1,300,000. I originally sorted the list from smallest to largest then did End(xlUp) and just began removing values from the bottom of the list until the sum was less that 1,300,000 but the issue i had was that the last number i was extracting was fairly large so the sum would be significantly below 1,200,000. What would be best is if I can write som VB code that will look at my list, pull values until the sum is less than 1,300,000 and then will only pull the next value if it is 100,000 or less... if the next value is greater than 100,000 just skip and look at next one.

This is the current list of numbers I am working with:

```
236,800
13,300
7,100
2,500
5,600
5,900
11,700
33,100
172,200
17,400
43,900
1,200
2,100
1,900
500
600
3,700
23,300
53,300
32,900
10,100
3,300
400
500
11,500
7,700
3,700
1,700
700
6,300
26,400
22,700
12,400
5,500
700
500
1,000
500
25,200
700
900
41,400
328,700
900
1,800
329,100
6,100
47,700
500
5,100
11,900
300
12,800
0
200
31,100
900
500
2,500
8,500
5,600
```

Thanks!

Comment: How many numbers are in this list?

Comment: the list is dynamic.. there can be anywhere from 10 numbers to 300 numbers @JohnColeman

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with a variation of the subset sum problem. It is almost certainly NP Complete so you can't expect a simple solution. If the list of numbers is small, it can be solved by the Solver as an integer programming problem (use variables which are constrained to be 0-1 in a column adjacent to the column containing the list, form the corresponding sumproduct, constrain its values to be between 1,200,000 and 1,300,000 and use the first decision variable as a dummy objective function). If the list is too large the built-in solver can't handle that many binary variables -- but you could always get the premium version from Front Line Systems (the maker of the Solver add-in). All of this is doable from VBA if you include the reference to the Solver add-in.

Alternatively, you could use a heuristic approach. Have a vector of 0's and 1's which determine what elements to select. Score such a vector by how close the corresponding sum comes to satisfying the constraints. Changing a 0 to 1 or vice versa either takes the sum closer to or farther away from satisfying the constraints. Start with a random vector. If any such change helps - make the best such change. Make such changes until no further such change helps. This is a local optima. If it satisfies the constraints - done. If not, start again. If this (iterated hill-climbing with random starts) doesn't work you could look into an evolutionary algorithm. You could code it yourself or see if the Solver version of evolutionary optimization helps (I don't have a lot of experience with that part of the solver and don't know what sort of constraints it has on problem size or problem formation).